# how to get root access in adb shell for unlocking pattern

Tags: android, adb, root

I wanna to unlock my phone then I read some other questions about this subject :
they say use `su` or `abd shell root` and some others like that but they don't work for me

I read an article that say use your settings.db for unlocking but I don't have **settings.db** in

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases
```

or when I want to delete `/data/system/gesture.key`  I need ***root access*** but I don't have any access to root .

what should I do ??

Comment: belongs to http://android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

Well,

root access isn't granted that easy. Android is designed to deny every normal attempt of the 'user' to become the 'roo user'. So, for every phone there's another method that might work.

`'su'`, `'adb shell root'` and such snippets only work if you gained root BEFORE typing this.

I don't know what device you have, but have a look at [forum.xda-developers.com](http://forum.xda-developers.com), search for your device an than look in the development forum of it for the root method!

DISCLAIMER: I am not responsible for any damage taken by your phone if you root it. To root a phone voids every right of warranty! So think about this twice before you do it!

Regards